# iPhone 7 recording issues

Tags: iphone, recording, voice-memo

For a while now my Voice Notes on WhatsApp record blank. I mean you can’t hear anything. The same goes for Voice Memos app.

I can make cell calls without a problem, use speech-to-text and even record a video with sound.

I also noticed that when I record a video on WhatsApp, after that the Voice Note works normally I can record but after that the next Voice Note is blank again.

My hand is not on the mic when I record and I don’t think I have another app that is using the mic.

I’m new to iOS so I’m not sure what’s going wrong.